# cannot abble to run es6 code on html file

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

When I make a JS file and run it in Terminal it successfully runs .
code:

```
function add(x,y){
    var sum = x+y;
    console.log(sum);

}
add(15,5);
```

this code gives me correct answer, but when I create an HTML file and link it with the same Javascript file and trying to run it in terminal a pop-up massage says "code language not supported or defined"

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="indaxi.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   
</body>
</html>
```

so , why is that ..?

Comment: It's not es6. It's es3

Comment: Where/how does this have anything to do with `facebook-javascript-sdk`? Please tag appropriately. (Tag removed.)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure that your file is referenced correctly. Here it is expected to be in the same folder as the HTML file that you have. As about the language, you can specify it as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="indaxi.js"></script>
```

Comment: type attribute is by default `text/javascript`

Comment: [Omitting the attribute, setting it to the empty string, or setting it to a JavaScript MIME type essence match, means that the script is a classic script, to be interpreted according to the JavaScript Script top-level production. Classic scripts are affected by the async and defer attributes, but only when the src attribute is set. **Authors should omit the type attribute instead of redundantly setting it.**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-type)

Comment: The error which says that code language is not specified or defined seems to indicate that the browser the asker uses behaves differently.